# how to get value from array of selectbox inputs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On button click i want to fetch selected value of multiple select boxes. i can able to fetch value from array of textboxes but im not able to get select box value. it returns empty array.

```js
$("#add_user_button").click(function(){
  

 var username=[];    
 $("input[name=username]").each(function(){
  username.push($(this).val());
 });

 var usertype=[];
 $("input[name=usertype]").each(function(){
  usertype.push($(this).val());
 }); 
 
  var ajaxdata={"UserName":username,"UserType":usertype}; 
  
   console.log(JSON.stringify(ajaxdata));
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="user_group">
        <input type="text" id="user_username" placeholder="User Name" name="username">
           <select id="user_usertype"  name="usertype">
                   <option value="1">Admin</option>
                   <option value="2">Normal</option>
              </select>
</div>

<div class="clone_user_input"><div id="user_group_1">
         <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="user_username" placeholder="User Name" name="username">
                 <select id="user_usertype"  name="usertype">
                   <option value="1">Admin</option>
                   <option value="2">Normal</option>
              </select>
     </div>                                                              
 </div>
  <button  id="add_user_button">Add User</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select is not input. Use:

```
var usertype=[];
$("select[name=usertype]").each(function(){
    usertype.push($(this).val());
});
```

Also note that you have duplicate IDs for elements. IDs should be always unique. You can rather use same class names as an alternative to this.